# Chatterbot_corpus not working, giving an atribute error

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am working on a chatbot using the python chatterbot and chatterbot_corpus, I am just at the point of getting the corpus. when I run the code I get an error in the corpus file saying

```
  parts = dotted_path.split('.')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

really it should just run and access the corpus files. any help would be appreciated, I will put all my code bellow.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import chatterbot_corpus

bot = ChatBot(
    'IKO',  
    logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
        'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter',
        'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'],
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
)

trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

trainer.train([
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.ai"
])


trainer.train([
"what is your name",
"my name is IKO",
"is your name IKO",
"yes"
])

trainer.train([
        "turn on the light",
        "ok turning the light on"
        ])


name = input("Enter Your Name: ")
print("Welcome to the Bot Service! Let me know how can I help you?")
while True:
    request=input(name+':')
    if request=='Bye' or request =='bye':
        print('Bot: Bye')
        break
    elif "turn" in request and "on" in request and "light" in request:
        sig = "light on"
        print(sig)
    else:
        response=bot.get_response(request)
        print('Bot:',response)
```

the entire error is:

runfile('C:/Users/jax02/OneDrive/Desktop/IKO/IKO/AI attempt 2.py', wdir='C:/Users/jax02/OneDrive/Desktop/IKO/IKO')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/jax02/OneDrive/Desktop/IKO/IKO/AI attempt 2.py', wdir='C:/Users/jax02/OneDrive/Desktop/IKO/IKO')

File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/jax02/OneDrive/Desktop/IKO/IKO/AI attempt 2.py", line 21, in 
"chatterbot.corpus.english.ai"

File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 133, in train
data_file_paths.extend(list_corpus_files(corpus_path))

File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 66, in list_corpus_files
corpus_path = get_file_path(dotted_path, extension=CORPUS_EXTENSION)

File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 30, in get_file_path
parts = dotted_path.split('.')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Add the complete traceback (error)

Comment: I added it to post. thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you are overwriting a variable that you already declared.

❌

```py
trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
```

✅

```py
list_trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
corpus_trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
```

Another problem is that when you train through `ListTrainer`, you have to pass a list to it, but when you train through `ChatterBotCorpusTrainer` you don't.
You can see this in the documentation.

[ListTrainer example](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/training.html#id3)

[ChatterBotCorpusTrainer example](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/training.html#id6)

So, let's make some changes (keeping in mind now the variables names have been changed)

❌

```py
corpus_trainer.train([
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.ai"
])
```

✅

```py
corpus_trainer.train(
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.ai"
)
```

In case you have not understood, here is what the final code would be like:

```py
list_trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
corpus_trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

corpus_trainer.train(
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings",
    "chatterbot.corpus.english.ai"
)

list_trainer.train([
    "what is your name",
    "my name is IKO",
    "is your name IKO",
    "yes"
])

list_trainer.train([
    "turn on the light",
    "ok turning the light on"
])
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you said and got a new error: 
  File "C:\Users\jax02\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\conversation.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.id = kwargs.get('id')

TypeError: descriptor 'id' for 'Statement' objects doesn't apply to 'Statement' object

Comment: Have you applied any other modifications to the code that are not reflected in this stackoverflow question?

It's look like a problem in the `get_response` method

Comment: I have changed absolutely nothing.